# Drawing a graphic and placing it inside a panel using a BorderLayout

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, border-layout

```
public MyLayout (){
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        panel.add(new GraphicsSurface(),BorderLayout.CENTER);


        frame.add(panel,BorderLayout.NORTH);

        frame.add(btn1,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true); 
    }
```

I'm creating a graphic placing it inside a panel

`panel.add(new GraphicsSurface(),BorderLayout.CENTER);`

and placing this panel inside a JFrame

`frame.add(panel,BorderLayout.NORTH);`

Except the graphic is displaying outside the JFrame

[image: JFrame]

Comment: Add `panel` to the center and see what happens

Comment: @peeskillet [Panel in CENTER](http://i.imgur.com/1fNbSaM.png)

Comment: Does that mean the problem is fixed? I don't know what it's supposed to look like. For better help, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I want the Graphic to be displayed centred at the top of the JFrame. I still have more components to add.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *"I want the Graphic to be displayed centred at the top of the JFrame. I still have more components to ad"*

In `GraphicsSurface` override `getPreferredSize` and give it the size you want (I guess the size of the clock

```
class GraphicsSurface extends JPanel {
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimenstion(..., ...);
    }
}
```

For `panel`, don't set the layout. The default `FlowLayout` will work perfectly (it also centers by default -yeeee!). What will happen is that the `GraphicsSurface` will maintain its preferred size, as `FlowLayout` will respect it. Then the `panel` will be stretched to the width of the frame (the height will remain the `GraphicsSurface`'s height), and the `GraphicsSurface` will be centered in the `panel`

With this you should be fine, adding the `panel` to the frame's `NORTH`. The center will be left for everything else.

Comment: (plus1) for overriding `getPreferredSize()` and not using setPreferredSize().

Answer (score 1):

You place your panel at frame NORTH.
In north, your panel will take only the widows width. So he has no height (or 1px height).

So try to define a size to your panel:

```
panel.setPreferedSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
```

Else, as suggested in comment, place your panel into the CENTER of the frame.

Replace:

```
frame.add(panel,BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

by

```
frame.add(panel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

In center, your panel will get the panel width and height (substract your button height).

Comment: Thanks, I thought the panel would automatically adjust to the size of the graphic. Setting the panel dimension solved my problem.

Comment: @user3922757, don't use the setPreferredSize() method. Instead, you should override the `getPreferredSize()` method of you custom panel. Only the panel should be aware of the proper preferred size of the component. Also, don't forget to "accept" the answer so people know the problem has been solved.